# Unexpected re.findall output

Tags: python, regex

Using python shell:

```
namesRegex=re.compile(r'Agent (\w)\w*')
namesRegex.findall('Agent Alice gave the secret documents to Agent Bob.')
```

**output**:['A', 'B']

the regular expression confused, me aren't we supposed to get [Agent A ,Agent B] ?

```
namesRegex.sub(r'Agent \1*****','Agent Alice gave the secret documents to Agent Bob.')
```

**output:**'Agent A***** gave the secret documents to Agent B*****'

could someone explain to me the last output and how it's relation works and valid with last Regular expression ?

Comment: You have a capturing group in your regex, so `findall` returns a list of the captured groups.

Comment: coud you expalin more ? are you saying by passing(\w) i'm looking for one word in that specific regular expression area that i created

Comment: `findall` only returns matches from capture groups if they are present in the regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.findall`: If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups.

You should replace `Agent (\w)\w*` by `(Agent \w)\w*` in case you keep the structure of the regex. If not, you only use `Agent \w`.

I also tried to test results on python.

```
import re

#case1
print("Case 1")
string = "Agent Alice gave the secret documents to Agent Bob."
regex = '(Agent \w)\w*'

match = re.findall(regex, string)
print(match)

#case2
print("Case 2")
string = "Agent Alice gave the secret documents to Agent Bob."
regex = 'Agent \w'

match = re.findall(regex, string)
print(match)
```

Result

```
Case 1
['Agent A', 'Agent B']
Case 2
['Agent A', 'Agent B']
```